# Basic CSS question- how to make this work in CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I heard is best to save CSS in another sheet which I did. I don't know how to make this part work in the CSS stylesheet `<div style=max-width:90%>` Right now I'm putting it like that & it works, just wondering if there's other better way to do it. site preview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAiak.jpg

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0c9n.jpg)

```html
    <!--home page-->
    <section class="home container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5 py-5 pl-5">
                <div style=max-width:90%>
                    <img class="img-fluid" alt=" " src="img/app_screens_01.png">
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto px-5">
                <h1 class="home-content-heading">This is just the beginning</h1>
            </div>
```

Comment: Regarding `<div style=max-width:90%>` you can set a class to it instead `<div class="myDIV">` then in you css file you can call it like that `.myDIV{ max-width:90%; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's always advised to keep all your styles in css files. You can assign class/id to the div & add style in css file.

```
<div class='some_class'>
```

In css file (Of course you have to call this css in html)

```
.some_class
  max-width:90%
```

Note :- Your class name or id name should be unique & meaningful for better understanding  & not like `some_class` which I used it just for example.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! it works, I have to read it couple times to understand what it means because I already have some div class going on top, but I guess I figure it out =D (funny thing I set the class to 'happy' it didnt work, I gave a more proper name like 'screenleft' it works.)

Comment: Perhaps consider properly formatted CSS given the relative experience taken from the OPs comments?